# How to host two node applications on bitnami MEAN stack server?

Tags: node.js, apache, mean-stack, bitnami

I have hosted two node application on Bitnami Mean stack server by taking reference from this [link](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Custom_Node.js_Application)

### Problems

1) According to this documentation my application should run on http://[your-IP-address]/myapp url but it is opening directly at http://[your-IP-address].

2) I have hosted two node applications running at 4000 and 5000 port. When you hit on ip it opens that application which is firstly placed in this file 
  "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf".

### content of bitnami-apps-prefix.conf

```
# Bitnami applications installed in a prefix URL
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/app1/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/app2/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/rockmongo/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

3) How to map url to open specific application.

### App1 settings -> httpd-app.conf

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

### App2 settings -> httpd-app.conf

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4000/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to map different paths at `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` in **httpd-app.conf** from each application.

**App1 settings -> httpd-app.conf**

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://127.0.0.1:5000/ 
ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:5000/ 
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

**App2 settings -> httpd-app.conf**

```
ProxyPass /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:4000/ 
ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:4000/
ProxyPass /app2 http://127.0.0.1:4000/ 
ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://127.0.0.1:4000/
```

You should add both `/app1/` and `/app1` to match the app root address with `/app1` and the rest of the addresses with `/app1/`. Otherwise the proxy wont be able to map your requests correctly in both cases.

If you want to map one of your applications as root (/), make sure to place that include at the end in your **bitnami-apps-prefix.conf** file:

```
# Bitnami applications installed in a prefix URL
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/app1/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/app2/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/rootapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

**Root application settings -> httpd-app.conf**

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```